# How do I rectify inconsistent Unresolved External errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, sfml, unresolved-external

I'm trying to wrap my head around C++ developement using the SFML library. I'm following a tutorial (http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Game-From-Scratch-CPP-Edition-Part-7.aspx), and using visual studio 2010.

A problem I keep running into regards unresolved externals. I'm really struggling with this, because unlike most errors I run into, it doesn't seem to a) have anything to do with the code, and b) doesn't behave consistently. Rather than give y'all a specific example and ask for help solving that one example, I'm hoping to develop a more reliable way of attacking these problems. I'll give you an outline of a common occurance though.

I have a solution with 8 header files and 8 cpp files that correspond to them. The solution is stable: It compiles and runs with no errors or warnings.

I'll go into a header file and add this line:

virtual void DoNothing();

I'll then go into the matching cpp file and write the method:

void DoNothing(){};

I compile and run, and get 5 unresolved external errors. They don't point to any line of code, so I don't really know how to fix them, but I obviously did something wrong. Fair enough. Trying to get back to a stable state, I delete the two lines of code I had inserted, and compile. Even though the code is identical to the last stable state, I get the same unresolved external errors.

Trying random things, I go into another cpp file and reverse the order of two included header files. The game compiles now. If I switch the order of the included header files back, it compiles.

What the hell are unresolved external errors? Why don't they seem to behave consistently with the code I've entered? How do I read them to find out what the problem is, and how do I avoid them in the first place?

Thank you.

ps: If there are more specific details I should provide, please just let me know.

Comment: In your example it looks like you are not qualifying the name. It probably should be `void SomeClass::DoNothing(){}`

Comment: please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

"Unresolved External" errors mean that your code is referring to something (usually a function or method, but can be a variable too) that does not exist. These are *link* errors, and not *compile* errors; that's why you don't get a line number and more helpful error messages.

Let me give you a little background on how C++ code is turned into an executable (and keep in mind that I'm simplifying things a bit.)

Each C++ source file (and not header file) in your project is compiled separately. A ".cpp" file and all the headers it includes are compiled into what is called an *object file* or *object code*. (These files have a ".obj" or ".o" extension.) You can also think of library files (that is ".lib" files on Windows and ".a" files on Linux) as a collection of these object files, stored for later use.

To produce the executable programs (e.g. the EXE or DLL file on Windows) all these object files are *linked* together are *voila*!

Now, the important thing here is that each source file is compiled *in isolation* and independent from other source files. So, if the code in one file calls a function that is implemented in another file, the compiler won't see the actual body of that function and can only assume that as long as the *declaration* of the called function is visible (i.e. the *prototype*, i.e. the line you write in headers,) then these files are going to be linked together eventually and will leave the task of actually making the call to the linker. This usually means that as long as you include the right headers, your compiler is going to be happy.

But the linker is going to be more tenacious and pedantic. At link time, you really really need to provide the body (i.e. the implementation) of all the functions that you use all over the project. It is your task to make sure that all the right object files and libraries are linked together and the implementation of each used function exists somewhere among them exactly once (no more, no less.)

This brings us to your problem. When you get an "unresolved external" linker error, this means that the body of a function you've called does not exist anywhere in object files and libraries that you are linking together.

Obviously, one of two things is happening. Either you have included the header for an external library, but have forgotten to link in the library file itself (which is not your problem here) or you've declared (i.e. written the prototype for) a function but have forgotten to implement its body.

Keep in mind that the linker is really strict here. If you declare something like this in your class:

```
class Foo {
    void bar (int x);
};
```

and then in your ".cpp" file, implement this function:

```
void bar (int x)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

then you'll get an unresolved external error if you actually call `Foo::bar()` anywhere in your program, because the implemented `bar()` is not a method of `Foo` (you should have implemented `void Foo::bar (int x) {}`.) Similar things happen if you slightly misspell or get the type of the arguments wrong or whatnot.

Reading linker errors and making sense from them *can* be hard. Sometimes, the name that the linker is complaining about (the "symbol" it says it can't find) is all mangled beyond recognition. This has to do with *Application Binary Interface*s (ABI) and several decades of history and precedence. Anyways, most of the time, if you look closely and the link error message, you can see what the function name was and check your code (or libraries) and try again.

Also, though it's rare, it sometimes happens that in order to solve some link issues, you have to resort to completely rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've seen behavior like this it has been because of a circular reference between projects.  For example, project A has a reference to an object/symbol implemented in project B while at the same time project B has a reference to an object/symbol from project A. Every time you build your solution, the tools have to compile one project first, then the other. If you make a change to the second project to be compiled, the first one cannot see the change on the first round of compilations and the build fails. If you manage to manually build project B (against a now obsolete copy of library B), then the solution starts to build correctly. More complex cycles are possible (e.g. A depends on B, which depends on C, which depends on A). You don't mention multiple projects explicitly, but I bet you have them.

These circular references are common on large solutions that have been around for a long time and have grown slowly over time. People get in habit of adding links from everything to everything because they need one function from *here*, a struct from *there*...

Hunt down these dependencies. You should be able to do a full clean rebuild from nothing but the source code. Your dependency tree should look like... Well, a tree; not a graph.